# ambiguity in qualification conversion

Tags: c++, type-conversion, constants, volatile, qualifiers

I think I either misunderstand something or something in the standard might be ambiguous. And it's regarding the qualification conversions.

According to the newest draft http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#1

> A cv-decomposition of a type T is a sequence of cvi and Pi such that T is “cv0 P0 cv1 P1 ⋯ cvn−1 Pn−1 cvn U” for n>0,

as to my understanding the decomposition of the type T:

```
using T1 = const char * const **;
```

might be following

- n = 2
- U = char
- cv2 = const
- P2 = *
- cv1 = const
- P1 - *
- cv0 = empty
- P0 = *

but since it's not said which direction the decomposition should go it (IMO) could be also interpreted the other way:

- n = 2
- U = char
- cv0 = const
- P0 = *
- cv1 = const
- P1 - *
- cv2 = empty
- P2 = *

It will make a difference for the following sentence http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#3.3 :

> If the cv1i and cv2i are different, then const is in every cv2k for 0 < k  < i.

Since for the first interpretation the sentence will never be fulfilled for the i = 1 or 2, while for the second interpretation the sentence will be true for i = 1 or 2.

My second doubt is, how to interpret the sentence

> If the cv1i and cv2i are different, then const is in every cv2k for 0 < k  < i.

For i = 0 or 1. For i = 0 or 1 the cv set is empty, thus we can say that all cv for this set have const, because all is none and there is no element in the set, but we can as well say that none element have const, since there is no element in the set.

Is there any place in the standard, that would explain how to exactly understand the cv decomposition and which direction this should go?

Comment: Note that the highest P in the sample you quote is `Pn-1`.  In both cases you have P2, so `n` must be **3** (not 2).  Note that also means you need a cv3 (which may be empty).

Comment: what do you mean with direction? The quote says "cv0 P0 cv1 P1 ⋯ cvn−1 Pn−1 cvn U" not "cvn Pn cvn-1 Pn-1 .... cv1 P1 cv0 U"

Comment: `const char * const **` is "pointer to pointer to const pointer to const char", so cv0 = {}, P0 = "pointer to", cv1 = {}, P1 = "pointer to", cv2 = {`const`}, P2 = "pointer to", cv3 = {`const`}, U = `char`.

Comment: @MartinBonner thank you for pointing this out. Now I understand the whole thing. Since I did not notice the cvn is for the U, then I did not know whether cvn-1 is for most outer or most inner pointer. Now it's clear. Thanks!

Comment: @DawidPilarski Can I encourage you to write that up as an answer?

Comment: @MartinBonner sure, I will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was given by @MartinBonner in the comments to the question.

I did not notice that just next to the U there is cvn, meaning that **constness decomposition goes from the most outer to the most inner pointer**.

(The cv with the biggest index will be closest to the type U).